# IText sharp works in Development Not in WebFarm Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, itext

Im Trying to convert my html to pdf using itextsharp. The Code Works fine in my development and testing Server. But when we deploy the same in Production we are getting error in the following line.

```
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream);
```

Our Development Server is in Web Server which Redirects the Request to another Webserver using WebFarm Environment.

I'm Not able to get any  error number. In Production unable to debug the same.

The same code work in Firefox only in IE we are facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the specifics of web farms but I recommend not writing directly to the `Response.OutputStream` in any scenario. Although it is completely valid to do so, debugging it can be really hard as you've found. Instead, write to a instance of `System.IO.MemoryStream` and then call `Response.BinaryWrite()` passing in the `MemoryStream`'s `.ToArray()`.